# Update every value of js array with dynamic key input (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

**Input js Array**

```
var foo = 
  [ { name: 'John',   age: '30', car: 'yellow' } 
  , { name: 'shayam', age: '13', car: 'blue'   } 
  , { name: 'ram',    age: '23', car: 'red'    } 
  ];
```

```
function poo(keyName, value)
  {
  // Change all the value of JSON array according to key and value 
  }
```

```
poo("car", "orange"); // 1
poo("age","20");     // 2
```

expected output 1

```
  [ { name: "John",   age: 30,   car: "orange" } 
  , { name: "shayam", age: 13,   car: "orange" } 
  , { name: "ram",    age: "23", car: "orange" } 
  ]
```

expected output 2

```
  [ { name: "John",   age: "20", car: "orange" } 
  , { name: "shayam", age: "20", car: "orange" } 
  , { name: "ram",    age: "20", car: "orange" } 
  ]
```

Comment: Can you please share what you have tried

Comment: Loop over the array, and for each element do `element[key] = value`. What part of this are you having trouble with?

Comment: var foo = [{ name: "John", age: "30", car: "yellow" },{ name: "shayam", age: "13", car: "blue" },{ name: "ram", age: "23", car: "red" } ];

let keyName='age'
let value='20'
let res=foo.map(a=>a.keyName:value) //  keyName is not able to recognized

Comment: `a[keyName] = value`.

Comment: should use forEach, not map

Comment: `var foo` is not JSON

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main key here is using dynamic object key with bracket notation, and use `forEach` and modify the target object without need to make a copy of it.

```js
var foo = [   { name: "John", age: "30", car: "yellow" },   { name: "shayam", age: "13", car: "blue" },   { name: "ram", age: "23", car: "red" }, ];

const poo = (key, value) => {
  foo.forEach(i => i[key] = value)
  return foo
}

console.log(poo('car', 'orange'));
console.log(poo('age', '20'));
```

Comment: better to write `foo.forEach(row => row[key] = value)`, -> by convention the letter `i` represents a numeric index.

Answer (score 0):

```
function poo(keyName, value) {
  foo.forEach(it => {
    it[keyName] = value
  })
}
```

Comment: If you're modifying the objects in place, there's no need to create a new array with `map`.

Answer (score 0):

```
function poo(keyName, value) {
    data = data.map((v) =>{
        v[keyName] = value;
        return v;
    })
}
```

Comment: If you're modifying the objects in place, there's no need to create a new array with `map()`.